# Ubuntu troubleshooting

Tags: ubuntu, linux, troubleshooting

I have a computer which keeps becoming unreachable, and a restart fixes the problem. It's under somewhat heavy load (high cpu, and high ram usage), but appears for the most part stable.

What's a good way to determine why it dies on me? I need to do this, while the computer is under load / in production.

E.G:

- What to look for in what logs? (Telltales for common problems? Any good log parser to sort by hardware component or common threads? How to find the timestamp/log entry of restart? Sort by error level? (critical, warning etc.))
- How to determine if ram is good from remote? (memtest, that can run alongside the rest of the system, similar to memtest from Hgi Design for windows)
- How to determine if there are any bad sectors on the harddrive? (How to look for read/write errors at the OS level? s.m.a.r.t. info is inaccurate at best, and not suitable to determine the extent of problems imo. - Looking for something similar to windows event viewer "disk error" category)
- How to find the last error before reboot took place in logs (what's a good way to parse logs) - partially answered by bulleric, but would like a concrete example of how to find the reboot entry/timestamp :)
- How to determine from logs (after any reboot), what caused it to become unresponsive (E.G look for exhausted ram telltales, if network is dropped, kernel panic) - In windows, the unexpected reboot event is logged as "critical", with a high probability of useful log entries just before this event - what to search for to find this in ubuntu?

***Edit:**

Based on the answers, I think I should clarify some:

The load is high, as it is a production server, not because a process is leaking ram, or burning cpu in some endless loop. This is normal, and is resulting in a huge logs, which are impractical to read line by line. I am familiar with htop, cacti, nagios, munin - and none of these address what I'm asking as they only show that the system is under heavy load (which I already know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must search the beginning of the problem 

**What to look for in what logs?**

The first thing is open top or if installed htop 
and search for overloadet tasks.. Many active store, process load .. 

if you find anything look in the logs 
tail -f /var/log/syslog
tail -f /var/log/dmesg

and lookup for errors or warnings that named with eventually overloadet tasks you found in top or htop.
In /var/log/  are many logfiles for many programms.


**How to determine if ram is good from remote?**

For this problem you can use a webbased analytic tool like Munin 
http://munin-monitoring.org/

Write a small bash script wich test the ram and when you get problems send a mail.
or use
nagios --> its a monitoring tool when you get problems with the ram you get an mail.

**How to determine if there are any bad sectors on the harddrive?**
find out what are your main harddrive or what are the harddrive you will test 
fdisk -l 

and check the harddrive(s) with fsck
(filesystemcheck: fsck check and repair a Linux file system)

**How to find the last error before reboot took place in logs (what's a good way to parse logs)**

You can use the tail command  with the lines option

tail -200  /var/log/syslog
tail -200  /var/log/dmesg

search for runlevel changes or shutdown sequences init 6 is the reboot runlevel
it can help when you use a pager (less)

tail -200 /var/log/syslog |less

I hope i can help a little bit :)

i wish you success

Comment: Do you have a concrete example on how to find the reboot log entry?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest installing [htop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) which gives a good overview over your system. You might also just use `top`.
If load is very high and the system stops responding, try `ps aux` and kill not needed suspicious processes or stop services using `sudo service $service stop`.

- `cd /var/log; ls -lrt` gives you the latest changed logs, check these
- `ssh server free -m` gives you information about memory and swap usage
- Bad sectors: use `smartctl` to check your disks
- I use `less` to look into logs and use keys `b` and `f` to scroll through them. Typing `/` lets you search for text. You can also use `grep` on a file to look for specific dates or text.

On ubuntu systems you might want to add your user to the group `adm`, so that you don't have to use `sudo` to read some of the files.

Another good idea is to install `logcheck` and set it up to send e-mails to you about what is going on.
If you have more than one computer that you take care of, you also might want to install a monitoring system like `xymon` to identify anomalies.

Good luck fixing your system!

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it in different way. Open few sessions - one with `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, second with `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`, third to monitor `top`, and fourth to run utility like `stress`. Now, simulate loaded system and see what happens. I suggest start with CPU load only and work from there. Also, ping the machine during the tests and monitor how it responds.

Please note - if you exhaust your RAM and hit the swap (unless on SSD) the machine will look exactly as you described it. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered hardware-related problems? I'd do the following in order:

1. Check for network firewall/config problem.
2. Check for hardware fault - try to plug in an off-the-shelf NIC and use that instead of the ones in use.
3. If you have a similar or identical machine around, get the box offline and test the hardware. At the same time see if you have the same problem on the replacement - good way to determine if the problem is hardware/software related.
4. If you don't have the hardware to spare it's time to make a business case for it.

Good luck!